# General expression for the age of something

Tags: english-to-japanese

I'm looking for a general way in Japanese to express the following:

> X is Y years old.

I know for human age we use 〜歳 and I have seen other expressions for buildings and trees (don't remember them off hand).

At least speaking about inanimate objects, is there a generic way to express age? Here is my guess (probably awkward):

> This car is 20 years old.
>   この車は２０年も古い

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not nearly as simple as in English or many other languages.

You could say:

> 「X + は + Y + 年前{ねんまえ}のものである。」
>
> 「X + は + Y + 年前からある。」
>
> 「X + は + Y + 年前**に**できた。」 ←「できた」 here can be replaced by a verb in the passsive voice form such as 「作{つく}られた」,「建{た}てられた」, etc.

For buildings and trees, however, we have common set expressions.

Buildings: 「このビルは築{ちく}Y年である。」

Trees: 「あの木は樹齢{じゅれい}Y年です。」

For food and liquor items where aging is an important part of their values, we often use the expression 「**Y年もの**」.  Unless used sarcastically, that expression generally carries a positive connotation with it.  We say:

「３０年もののワイン」、「これは４年もののミソです。」, etc.

Finally, we would ***never*** say:

> 「この車は２０年**も**古い。」 to mean "This car is 20 years old."

The only times when we use 「**も**古い」 is when we say "A is Y years older than B." and emphasize that Y is a ***large*** number　- "A is much older than B".  The 「も」 is for emphasis and it is often used in combination with 「より」.　　You can say:

> 「このBMWは、あのトヨタ**より**１５年**も**古い。」

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Regarding も, since I have seen the expression ５年も前, I thought "５年も古い" (just to emphasize it was a long time ago) would also be acceptable, but from what you are saying it isn't.